# What are some examples of microscopic quantities?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Mass, volume, energy, entropy, temperature, pressure are some macroscopic quantities. Which means we can think of them even without considering the molecular nature of matter.

**What are some examples of microscopic quantities?** These must be the quantities to make sense of which we need to consider the molecular nature of matter.

Comment: The heat capacity of an ideal gas as a function of temperature is dependent on the microscopic constituents, i.e. it will be different if you have a monoatomic, diatomic or larger molecule.

Answer (score 2):

Macroscopic and microscopic do not refer to the property itself but to what information we use to calculate it. We can calculate entropy by the formula
$$S = \int_0^T \frac{dQ}{T}$$
which can be done in the lab using a calorimeter and a thermometer.

Or it can be calculated by counting all microstates of a system at fixed $E$, $V$ and $N$, which requires detailed information about the state of the system at the molecular level.

Macroscopic (or classical) thermodynamics obtains relationships between properties without reference to molecular state. Statistical mechanics (which we might call "microscopic thermodynamics") does the same using molecular arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, a microscopic property would be the specific amount of velocity, momentum, or kinetic energy possessed by each individual atom in the larger ensemble. When solving problems related to the *macroscopic* pressure or temperature of the ensemble, it is far easier to work with properties related to the *averages* of those microscopic properties. This avoids having to individually track and account for the kinetic energies of say 10exp23 individual atoms and all of their collisions with one another, which would be a horrendous task.

Comment: What you said, is exactly how I have studied about macro and micro quantities and an issue in this explanation is what motivated me to ask this ques. Wouldn't velocity, momentum and energy then be classified as both macro and micro quantities? I can define velocity for bulk as well as for a single molecule. Same goes for energy. Does this mean quantities like mass, velocity, momentum, energy are both microscopic and macroscopic?

Comment: the macro quantity related to the overall speed with which the parcel of hot gas is moving in the back of a truck on the highway is completely irrelevant to the thermodynamic description of the pressure or temperature of that same parcel of gas. I think you are confusing these two realms.